# How to properly align my continuous equations?

Tags: align, multline

I just want to make "for N = 1" and "for N = 2" left justified. How can I manage this?

```
\begin{multline}
\begin{aligned}
\underline{\textbf{for N = 1:}}& \\ \Big\{ 1 -\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k - 4\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k - \lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k + 2\lambda_2 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3\Big\}\textcolor{red}{\boldsymbol{\prescript{}{l+1}{\delta}_{1}^k}} + \\ \Big\{ 2\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k + 4\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k + 2\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k - 2\lambda_2 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3\Big\}\textcolor{red}{\boldsymbol{\prescript{}{l+1}{\delta}_{2}^k}} + \\ \Big\{ -\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k - \lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k \Big\}\textcolor{red}{\boldsymbol{\prescript{}{l+1}{\delta}_{3}^k}} = \textcolor{blue}{\boldsymbol{\delta_{1}^{k-1}}}
\\
\\
\\
\underline{\textbf{for N = 2:}}& \\ \Big\{ 1 -\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k - 4\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k - \lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k + 2\lambda_2 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3\Big\}\textcolor{red}{\boldsymbol{\prescript{}{l+1}{\delta}_{1}^k}} + \\ \Big\{ 2\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k + 4\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k + 2\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k - 2\lambda_2 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3\Big\}\textcolor{red}{\boldsymbol{\prescript{}{l+1}{\delta}_{2}^k}} + \\ \Big\{ -\lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k - \lambda_1 \left(\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k\right)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k \Big\}\textcolor{red}{\boldsymbol{\prescript{}{l+1}{\delta}_{3}^k}} = \textcolor{blue}{\boldsymbol{\delta_{1}^{k-1}}}
\label{SingleDropletEqns}
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
```

[image: This is the output of this code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest that you use `aligned` environments inside `equation` (not `multline`) environments and use `&` alignment markers. I'd also get rid of all `\left` and `\right` directives and place the `For $N=1$` and `For $N=2$` labels outside the math material. Finally, in order to make the `\delta`-terms less turgid-looking, I'd boldface only `\delta` but not its pre- and post- arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools,bm}

\begin{document}
\noindent
For $N = 1$:
\begin{equation}\label{SingleDropletEqn1}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bigl\{1 -  \lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k 
         - 4\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k 
         -  \lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k 
         + 2\lambda_2 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \bigr\}
&\textcolor{red}{\prescript{}{l+1}{\bm{\delta}_{1}^k}} \\
{}+ \bigl\{  2\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k 
           + 4\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k 
           + 2\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k 
           - 2\lambda_2 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \bigr\}
&\textcolor{red}{\prescript{}{l+1}{\bm{\delta}_{2}^k}} \\
{}+ \bigl\{-\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k 
           -\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k \bigr\}
&\textcolor{red}{\prescript{}{l+1}{\bm{\delta}_{3}^k}} 
=\textcolor{blue}{\bm{\delta}_{1}^{k-1}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\medskip\noindent
For $N = 2$:
\begin{equation} \label{SingleDropletEqn2}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bigl\{1 -  \lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k 
         - 4\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k 
         -  \lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k 
         + 2\lambda_2 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \bigr\}
&\textcolor{red}{\prescript{}{l+1}{\bm{\delta}_{1}^k}} \\
{}+ \bigl\{  2\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k 
           + 4\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{1}^k 
           + 2\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k 
           - 2\lambda_2 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \bigr\}
&\textcolor{red}{\prescript{}{l+1}{\bm{\delta}_{2}^k}} \\
{}+ \bigl\{-\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{2}^k 
           -\lambda_1 (\prescript{}{l}{\delta}_{1}^k)^3 \prescript{}{l}{f}_{0}^k \bigr\}
&\textcolor{red}{\prescript{}{l+1}{\bm{\delta}_{3}^k}} 
=\textcolor{blue}{\bm{\delta}_{1}^{k-1}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Though, my interface is giving me couple of errors like "Undefined  Control Sequence". I avoided using 

"\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably"

because I am using a sample template my uni provided.

Comment: @Peclet - An "Undefined Control Sequence" message doesn't come along all alone. Do please tell which control sequences aren't defined. Is it maybe `\bm`? If so, did you load the `bm` package?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no solid knowledge on TeX, I had to search for \bm before replying you. Yes, problem was \bm so I loaded that one. Now it seems like it is working properly. I sincerely thank you for your effort and time.